# Passing data outside of Wordpress possible?

Tags: api

We're exploring some possibilities to upgrade our web development tools in using Wordpress, but we're concerned whether or not there is a good plug-in to build custom forms in WordPress and pass data outside of Wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an affiliate of Gravity Forms and I'm sorry if this offends someone, but based on my own custom form development experiences I can recommend it.

Gravity Forms has very good API documentation that helps when customizing forms. For example on one site I used Advanced Custom Fields metafields as Gravity Forms radio field options.

Gravity Forms also has different hooks you can use to manipulate form entries before/after the form/email notifications are saved/sent.

Comment: Thank you! if we use Gravity Forms are we going to be able to send data outside of Wordpress?

Comment: I think that should be doable. For example with gform_after_submission hook. Then it's up to you to decide how you want to send the data outside of WordPress. I've been meaning to play around with that hook and the WordPress HTTP API (https://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API) to feed the entries to some other API, but haven't had the spare time to do it yet.

Comment: Ok, thank you! We will take a look at this plug-in!